# c# enum flag check if string is in flag

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum WeekDays
{

    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64
}
```

And if I do:

```
var weekDays = WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday | WeekDays.Friday;
```

How can I check if a string for example `Monday` is set in the weekDays?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Which bit's not working for you? Parsing a string, or checking if the relevant bit is set in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this

```
WeekDays days = WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday;

string monday = "Monday";

WeekDays day;
if (Enum.TryParse(monday, true, out day))
{
    if (days.HasFlag(day))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Has {0}", monday);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Does not have {0}", monday);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("invalid string");
}
```

First you can use `Enum.TryParse` to parse the string to an enum value or determine if the string is invalid.  Then use `HasFlag` to see if it is included.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following code. You can use the `HasFlag` attribute:

```
class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum WeekDays
        {

            Monday = 1,
            Tuesday = 2,
            Wednesday = 4,
            Thursday = 8,
            Friday = 16,
            Saturday = 32,
            Sunday = 64
        }

        private static string result;

        static void Main()
        {
            var wd = new WeekDays();
            Console.WriteLine(wd.HasFlag(WeekDays.Monday));

            wd = WeekDays.Monday;

            Console.WriteLine(wd.HasFlag(WeekDays.Monday));

            bool is_defined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(WeekDays), "Monday");

            Console.WriteLine(is_defined);

            bool is_not_defined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(WeekDays), "Mondays");

            Console.WriteLine(is_not_defined);

            bool has_flag_by_string = Enum.TryParse<WeekDays>("Monday", out wd);

            Console.WriteLine(has_flag_by_string);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

*EDIT*

Added the ability to check if attribute exists by string.

*EDIT 2*

Added the `Enum.TryParse<>` to parse the string value.

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think the OP is saying how do they know that given the string "Monday" that the corresponding enum value is set in a give `WeekDays` value.

Comment: @juharr added the TryParse to get what he want based on your comment.

Comment: FYI you don't have to include the generic type in the `TryParse` call as it will be inferred from the out parameter.

Comment: Very true, I do it out of habit and readability so I know what Type I'm working with.